# Manage a simple private area with Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I'd like to have ideas on how to manage a simple private members area with wordpress. I have to access this area with a simple login form on the homepage. This will be a one user authentication (one username/pass for all the users). In this private area the user can download some pdf and misc files uploaded in some way using wordpress.

So do you have any idea on how to manage all this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can add different password for every single post/page in Wordpress. So create page and add password protection to it.

Answer (score 0):

You could also do a check in the template to only show content if the user is logged in:

```
<?php if ( is_user_logged_in() ) { ... } ?>
```

More details for a similar approach is [shown here](http://new2wp.com/noob/wordpress-members-only-pages/).